# python how to read read any specific column of row line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have an csv file with multiple column. I want want to read an url column line by line then visit every url.
here my csv look like:

```
url          sku    
https://..   F-01    
https://..   F-02
```

I want to do somethings like this:

```
for i in url:
    visit_every_url = requests.get(i)
```

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('some_data.csv', usecols = ['url','sku'], low_memory = True)`
later
`df['new-value'] = 'updated'+df['sku']`

Comment: whoa - @boyenec your update totally changes the question. please clarify how/when df should be updated, and post what you have tried and what's not working.

Comment: Michael Delgado I want to somethings like this `for i in url: visit_every_url = requests.get(i)`

Comment: please see [ask]. edit your question to clarify your intention - don't clarify in comments. and that example you give accesses a URL - it doesn't have anything to do with a CSV. so please fully describe what you want to happen in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: what about the code you posted doesn't do what you want? "something like this" -- do you mean exactly like that? because that should work (if you change it to `for i in df.url.values`). if not exactly like that, then please describe what you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

Using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
cat url_csv                                                                                                                                                                                                             
url          sku    
https://google.com   F-01    
https://duckduckgo.com/   F-02 

import csv 
import requests

with open('url_csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        r = requests.get(row['url'])
        print(r.url)

https://www.google.com/
https://duckduckgo.com/
```

I took a guess at what the `delimiter` is in your CSV file. You need to verify whether it is actually space delimited or tab delimited.

Comment: Adrian Klaver  getting this error `KeyError: 'img-url'`

Comment: Well according to your file example the field name is `url` not `img_url`. If you want an actual answer you will need to update your question with the file information and code you are really using as well as the exact error messages.

Comment: Adrian Klave I changed the name url to img-url but why getting this error ?

Comment: I have no idea. Read my previous comment and take the steps requested, otherwise there is no way to answer this.